# Different guid is generated by uuid3 in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I recently migrated to Python 3.8.2 from Python 2.7.14 and ran into this issue.

```
import uuid

name="Test"
guid = str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, str(name.encode('utf8')))).upper()
print(guid)
```

Python 2 returns

```
5F210EFC-8898-3B6D-BAEE-94274CD64ADB
```

Python 3 returns

```
E8BEDE5C-66A5-36D6-87D5-6D50D4AEA4CF
```

My feature relies on generating the same guids based on "*name*". The first release was done with Python 2.7.14 and the next one is supposed to be with Python 3.8.2.

1. Is there any way we can generate the same guids as Python 2 from Python 3?
2. Why is it different in both versions of Python?

Comment: This bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue34145 seems to provide an explanation of what is going on. It seems like it won't be addressed considering how late it was reported. In fact if you take your code and run it as this in python 3: `str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, str(name))).upper()` you will get the Python2 result.

Answer (score 1):

On python 3.6, the following seems to work:

```
import uuid

name="Test"
guid = str(uuid.uuid3(uuid.NAMESPACE_DNS, name)).upper()
# 5F210EFC-8898-3B6D-BAEE-94274CD64ADB
```

Comment: I've tried 3.7 and 3.8 and with that code not specifying the encoding yields the same python 2 result as well. From the comment I made in the question, this was in fact reported for an improvement, but with the Py2 EOL no need to address: https://bugs.python.org/issue34145